# Will Google Navigation work without WiFi on Android tablet

Tags: tablet, google-maps-navigation

I have a Toshiba Excite tablet with android ice cream that has WiFi only (no cellular) that has Google Navigation (Beta) app on it and also Google map (Beta) app. I want to use the tablet in London England and Paris France. Will it work while walking around the city if I can't stay connected to WiFi?

If you think it won't work, what app can I use offline that will?

Comment: Partly. Does your tabby at least have GPS? Otherwise Navigation won't be able to work. How should it know where you are?

Comment: @Izzy Your forgetting the map download ;)

Comment: Nah, I don't. That could be done beforehand (e.g. at the hotel room), while still having WiFi. It's called "pre-caching" :) But without GPS *and* without network, there's no way to get the location. So the navi is not more than any paper map then.

Answer (score 3):

It most likely will work, depending on a few facts:

- your device must have GPS built-in
- you must have the map data downloaded while connected to WiFi (e.g. using [Maps (-) Offline Navigation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=coderminus.maps), which fills Google Map's cache)
- for navigation, you must have calculated the route in advance

I'm not sure whether Google Maps supports pre-calculation for navigation -- but even if, there's another restriction: once you hit a "closed road" (road works or the like), you're lost -- it cannot do a re-calculation of the route without network.

Also, getting a fix on GPS might be a lot slower (unless you aquire your fix while still connected to WiFi). Background is: To get a fix, GPS needs to know where which satellites are. These data are contained in what's called the [Almanac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_signals#Navigation_message). While [AGPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS) downloads those data from the network (e.g. via mobile data), "plain GPS" does not have this feature, and thus needs to get the data directly from the satellites -- which obviously is not as fast.

If it does not work with *Google Maps*, there are several alternatives to be found on the Google Playstore. I successfully used [Locus Map Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menion.android.locus) this way, so I know it *does* work. *Locus* lets you download map data directly from within the app, from different sources, and also offers pre-calculation of routes. This app is just one example, there are a lot more available.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer: Yes you can

<sup>(no Google tho...)</sup>

## Explanation:

There are [8 Toshiba Excite](http://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?sQuickSearch=yes&sName=Toshiba%20Excite) tablets currently in the market, all with GPS capabilities:

```
┌──────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┐
|     TABLET FULL NAME     |    GPS CAPABILITIES     | 
├──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┤
| Toshiba Excite Pro       | Yes                     |
├──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┤
| Toshiba Excite Write     | Yes                     |
├──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┤
| Toshiba Excite Pure      | Yes                     |
├──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┤
| Toshiba Excite 10 SE     | Yes                     |
├──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┤
| Toshiba Excite 10 AT305  | Yes                     |
├──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┤
| Toshiba Excite 7.7 AT275 | Yes, with A-GPS support |
├──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┤
| Toshiba Excite AT200     | Yes, with A-GPS support |
├──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┤
| Toshiba Excite 13 AT335  | Yes, with A-GPS support |
└──────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┘
```

This means that any of the existent Toshiba Excite Tablets have GPS and can perform map navigation.

<sup>Official Toshiba Excite product page [here](http://us.toshiba.com/tablets/excite/).</sup>

---

Based on the question dilemma, I've solved the same issue about one year ago with the following setup:

## [Navfree: Free GPS Navigation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.navfree.android.OSM.ALL&hl=en)

[image: Navfree screenshot]

> Navfree is a completely free navigation app that offers turn-by-turn directions, spoken and on-screen instructions, **offline map use and address search** and live search via Google and Microsoft Bing, among many other features.
>
> The **maps it uses are available for free download** from the Navfree Store. The map data is stored on your device so there is no need for a constant data connection while driving. It also allows you to browse maps anytime, anywhere without paying for data connections, which means no costly roaming charges when abroad.
>
> It uses **high-quality, open-source map data from OpenStreetMap** that has been created and is continually improved by as many as 400,000 users around the world. If you see a problem, you can help to improve the quality of the maps by signing up to www.openstreetmap.org.

<sup>I've highlighted the important stuff...</sup>

## Steps taken:

1. Download the map(s) for the location(s) you are traveling to:

   You can do this directly from the application:

   - Touch your device "menu" button;
   - Touch "Upgrades";
   - Select the maps you wish to download.
2. Test you map download by opening the application and plotting a root:

   I've done this while in a garage underground, no GPS signal, but still the map data I've downloaded contained all necessary requisites to plot the root, avoid tool charges and stuff...
3. To best acquire a GPS signal when you're on your destination, what I've done was get to a place without tall buildings around, to have the closest to 360º of clear sky as I could. In about 1min GPS signal was fixed.

   From here, GPS was at "poor" while inside city streets surrounded by tall builds, but the navigation was very satisfying with a very small margin of error from time to time (2 to 5 meters).

Comment: Be careful. Navfree helps itself to your contacts and phone numbers.

Answer (score -1):

It *will not work* for 2 reasons:

1. It would take *a very long time* to get a GPS fix without AGPS.
2. You have to be connected to the internet to download the map data.

There are a few offline map options on Google Play - you just have to look for them, [this is one of them](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapswithme.maps).

One other thing, make sure the tablet has GPS. Some of the cheaper ones don't.

Comment: You can pre-cache maps from within the GMaps app itself (check the "Lab" options). Though the area is restricted. And of course there are other pre-caching apps, as you already wrote (e.g. [Maps (-) Offline Navigation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=coderminus.maps)). Sure GPS fix will take a bit longer -- but that could also be minimized by aquiring a fix before leaving the WiFi cover (and then keeping GPS on).

Comment: @Izzy The GPS fix would soon go, and one wouldn't be able to acquire another fix. Also, what if the pre-caching not far enough?

Comment: I've never seriously tested this, but I've never noticed a delay when getting a GPS fix without the network, either; I suspect that the benefit of AGPS is small.

Comment: That depends. When a fix is achieved, the current Almanach (with Satellite data) is up-to-date, so it does not need to be re-downloaded. That download is what obviously takes longer done from a satellite than done from the network (which is what AGPS does).

Comment: I'd love to somehow delete the almanac so that I could watch it re-download it, but I can't figure out how.  I tried clearing the cache and data for the Maps app, but I assume that didn't delete the almanac, since it deduced my location in about three seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Still a little confused. Will any of the free suggested apps work if i'm in the US but the map is for London or Paris? I would like to test the app before traveling to the city.

Comment: @offby1 [GPS Status & Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) does that (amongst other things).